# UICollectionView how to query from Parse

Tags: ios, parsing, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView and I need download images to UIImage cell. How can I do it with Parse? The fact is that I need the class Parse download all the images.

This is my source code sample:

```
- (void)runQuery {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SwapPost"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // You obviously need better error handling in here...
    self.myImage = objects;
    [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
}
 ];
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    // This is an assumption
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.myImage.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed with this code:

**(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:**

```
(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        // This is an assumption
        return [receivedObject count];
    }
```

**(NSInteger)collectionView:**

```
(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        self.imageCell.image = [NSArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```